# JPA: Map a group of table columns extracted by native query to entity

Tags: jpa, jpql

I know that it is possible using `@SqlResultSetMapping` but I want to select not whole entity from the database but some fields and then map i to my entity using one of the constructor which accept that fields. Is that possible to map result with `@EntityResult` for only a few `@FieldResult`? I was trying to do that and all the time I get error which said that there is not specify mapping for some fields which exist in that entity.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of @SqlResultSetMapping is that you have to select all the columns.

The alternate way of doing this manually iterate over the DB result and populate your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using `JPA 1.0` your only option (not considering the manual mapping, of course), is to use `@SqlResultSetMapping` and map the whole table columns. With `JPA 2.1` you can add a `javax.persistence.ConstructorResult` (see docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)) to map only the needed columns.

Comment: Ok, and based on the specified parameters it will figure out which constructor use? What about naming if fields have different names than columns in table, which I should use in @ColumnResult? For example I get from table field nameEnglish but i want to map it to name in my entity?